# verbs with preposition construction with object and sentence as object?

Tags: verb-usage

when it comes to verbs with prepositions I get confused. 
for example hoffen comes with auf. 
which combinations are correct?

1- ich hoffe ein gutes Jahr.

2- ich hoffe **auf** ein gutes Jahr.

3- ich hoffe , (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

4- ich hoffe **es**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

5- ich hoffe **auf es**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

6- ich hoffe **darauf**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

which constructions are correct and why? should that dass be there always?

Edit1: numbers are corrected

Edit2: Why *ich hoffe **auf es*** is wrong? **es** is akkusativ and is comming after auf, **es** can be correlated here?

Comment: colloquialism: "Guten Rutsch!" or "Guten Rutsch ins Neue Jahr"

Comment: "Auf es" does not work the same way as "Ich hoffe darauf" cannot be translated with "I hope on it" but you say "I hope so". The only thing which is quite similar and works is "I hope for him/her/it that ..." which translates to "I hoffe für ihn/sie/es, dass ...".

Answer (score 1):

There are various forms of *hoffen*:

### hoffen + *object*

There are not many nouns you can hope. Most often you describe the object in a full sentence or a clause with *dass*. If the subject of this clause is the same as in the main sentence, you may as well use an infinitive clause with *zu*. Examples:

> Ich hoffe das Beste.
>
> Ich hoffe, Sie hatten ein gutes Jahr.
>
> Ich hoffe, dass Sie ein gutes Jahr hatten.
>
> Ich hoffe, bald befördert zu werden.

A correlate *es* is only used as a stand-alone reference to the last sentence:

> Wird 2020 ein gutes Jahr? 
>     Ich hoffe es. / Das hoffe ich.
>
> Wird Xyz wieder gewählt? 
>     Ich hoffe nicht. / Das hoffe ich nicht.

### hoffen + auf + *nominal phrase (acc.)*

This is the most common form:

> Ich hoffe auf ein gutes Jahr.
>
> Ich hoffe auf eine Beförderung.

You may replace the nominal phrase by a *dass*-clause or an infinitive clause with *zu*.
In general, this would require a correlate *es* in the main sentence, but *es* cannot be used with any preposition: *auf es* is as wrong as *ohne es*, *neben es* etc. You must use *darauf* instead:

> Ich hoffe darauf, dass Sie ein gutes Jahr haben werden.
>
> Ich hoffe darauf, bald befördert zu werden.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- ich hoffe ein gutes Jahr.

Wrong.

> 2- ich hoffe **auf** ein gutes Jahr.

OK

> 3- ich hoffe , (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

*dass* mandatory

> 4- ich hoffe **es**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

Wrong (*es*), *dass* mandatory

> 5- ich hoffe **auf es**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

Wrong (*auf es*), *dass* mandatory

What do you actually expect *es* / *auf es* should emphasize in that sentence?

> 6- ich hoffe **darauf**, (dass+/-) Sie ein gutes Jahr haben.

*dass* mandatory

Comment: Thanks for your response, why hoffe es AND hoffe auf es are wrong ?

Comment: @orodeous Because that's not correct German language.

Comment: but why? I mean based on which grammatical rule?

Comment: @orodeous Let's turn that over, and let you explain what grammatical rule you think that makes that it's correct. You can [edit](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/55812/edit) your question please?

Comment: In example #3 you could also rearrange the words of the second clause: *Ich hoffe, Sie haben ein gutes Jahr* - in this case there is **no dass**. This would be absolutely idiomatic *in spoken language*, but not so good style *in written language*